# PHP foreach statement split names MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a PHP script which interacts with my MySQL database. In my database I've got multiple columns, like:

'temp_0_state', 
'temp_0_color', 
'temp_1_state', 
'temp_1_color', 
'temp_2_state', 
'temp_2_color'
etc etc. till
'temp_50_state', 
'temp_50_color'

All 50 records contain under the 'temp_xxx_state' a name or will be empty ("") and
under 'temp_xxx_color' a color.

I can show all the colors of the 50 records manually, like

```
  if ($user['temp_0_state'] == "") {
  } else {
     echo . $user['temp_0_color'] . ;
     }
  if ($user['temp_1_state'] == "") {
  } else {
     echo . $user['temp_1_color'] . ;
     }
  if ($user['temp_2_state'] == "") {
  } else {
     echo . $user['temp_2_color'] . ;
     }
```

etc etc till

```
  if ($user['temp_50_state'] == "") {
  } else {
     echo . $user['temp_50_color'] . ;
     }
```

But it'll be easier, and to reduce the amount of php code, to use a foreach statement on the number in the middle of the column name for all records between 0 and 50 (0 < n < 50).
How can I split the names and use a foreach statement on the number 0 till 50 between the underscores?

Comment: Dynamic column names doesn't seem like the best approach tbh; this feels like a workaround that could be avoided with a different database structure.

Comment: I was expecting this answer... Problem is, i'm using someone elses database and can't change anything to that.

Comment: I figured there might be a reason - which is why I only commented rather than attempted an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I did not tested but you can give a try this:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 50; $x++) {

    $column = 'temp_'.$x.'_state';
    $color  = 'temp_'.$x.'_color';
    if ($user[$column] == "") {

    } else {
        echo $user[$color];
    }

}
```

Comment: OP is using `state` and `color` columns

Comment: no, that works! But I had also some other features in the same code which I had to add.

Comment: You should update `if ($user[$column] == "") {` by the opposite condition `if ($user[$column] != "") {` so you don't need to write the else line.

Comment: @Dacobah you do not know if OP have or have not need for it. ..

Answer (score 0):

A for statement would be more convenient in this situation, as you already know the maximum of records, according to your description:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 50; $i++) {
    if (!empty($user['temp_'.$i.'_state'])) {
        echo $user['temp_'.$i.'_color'];
    }
}
```

Please check the official for loop documentation to learn more about it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php